# Failing to resume from suspend

Tags: suspend-resume

I can't resume from suspend and I have an idea that Zram or prefetch cause this. I have a blinking cursor when trying to resume. I'd like to try turning zram off, but I was unlucky to find the command using google

Running `dmesg|less` i have seen the following lines

```
nautilus[2057]: segfault at a8 ip 0000000000486d44 sp 00007fff7d448e10 error 4 in nautilus[400000+159000]
```

running swapon:

```
 swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition   101372  0   -1
/dev/sda5                               partition   3906556 0   -2
/dev/zram0                              partition   1799092 0   100
/dev/zram1                              partition   1799092 0   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`. It will show you what your  system does as it enters and leaves suspended  state. See `man pm-action` and `dpkg -L pm-utils`. Diligent reading will show you how to add a script to the process, or simply mask one of the existing scripts. Oh, yes, read the scripts to see what's really going on.